# How to make a general function to create crossfilter.js dimensions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I am trying to make a general funtion to create crossfilter.js dimensions and groups. Up to now, I created an specific one depending on the key names (names of the columns) of the data this way (Example with 'Weekday' column):

```
DataArray= crossfilter(Data);
dimName = DataArray.dimension(function (d) { return d.Weekday; });
groupName= dinName.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInit);
```

This works, obviously, well, but I want to create a general funtion which can create the dimensions, no matter the name of the columns. I had thougth doing this:

```
var x = Data[0];
var keyNames= d3.keys(x);

dimName = DataArray.dimension(function (d) { return d.keyNames[0]; });
...
```

This doesn't work because 'd.keyNames[0]' is, obviously, wrong.
How can I pass the keyNames to the return of the function 'd. '??

I hope I explained well.

Comment: Do you want to create a dimension for each key? If not, how do you want to choose key(s) from the input data?

Comment: Yes , I want to create one dimension for each key. The problem is that I am using Flask to buid a web app so, previously, the user selects 5 variables between 25 from an html FORM, then a python function prepare the data acording to diferent options the user choose. Once the data is prepare, is sent to the html file as .json. That is the problem, I do not know, in advance, those 5 variables that have been choosen.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
dimName = DataArray.dimension(function (d) { return d.Weekday; });
```

with

```
dimName = DataArray.dimension(function (d) { return d["column name"]; });
```

This would work even if the column name has spaces.

Hence, the final version would be:

```
dimName = DataArray.dimension(function (d) { return d[keyNames[0]]; });
```